# What is the Load referred to RS-485?

Tags: communication, rs485

This is my first time knowing what rs-485 is and I am computing the power consumption between only two (2) rs-485 transceivers [SN65C1167](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn65c1168.pdf). As I read the datasheet, i became confused on the term "load" because i am looking for their current consumption to solve for power. Image below will make you understand in short what i don't understand fully.

[image]

upon researching what is load, i bump into this image below.

[image]

and reading this [article about rs-485 by TI](https://e2e.ti.com/blogs_/b/analogwire/archive/2016/03/08/rs-485-basics-how-to-calculate-unit-loads-and-the-maximum-number-of-nodes-on-your-network) calculating "UNIT LOAD". Is the Load referred on datasheets saying "NO LOAD" means "NO UNIT LOAD"?

Comment: What happens if those output pins are short circuited to +V or GND? Or the load resistance RL (in "Driver Section" table) is much less than 100 ohms?

Comment: In real life application, how does this output pins are shorted aside from what I have read on some articles like EMC? if such short happens, this output pins could exceed on its max current drive damaging receivers, right? and this can be deal with using galvanic isolation ICs (so far from what i read).

Answer (score 2):

Absolute maximum ratings should never be achieved. They just tell you when the chip will be damaged.

If you want to know the maximum supply current (to size your power supply) during normal operation **look at the "Short-circuit output current".**

In practice the current consumption will depend on the total bus load ie. how many devices are on the bus, if they all have 1 unit load (there are transceiver chips that represent 1/4 or 1/8 unit load) and termination type.

Comment: Thanks and sorry if i don't understand why short circuit output current? why is that? and So if i have only a simple setup of 2 rs-485 talking to each other, that'll be a total of 2 bus load? not a 1 unit load since there is 2 nodes in total and not 32 nodes? how much current would each transceiver consumes?

Comment: For reliability - size you power supply for the pessimistic short-circuit output current. The AVERAGE current will also depend on your data (how much, how often, how fast), so you could undersize the power supply and hope that capacitors will allow to "ride-through" moments of higher consumption.

Comment: Don't forget to consider the load imposed by the two termination resistors.  Typically these are 120 ohms each, one at each end of the bus.

Comment: @filo the setup is using the rs485 with SPI for long distance transaction as per this [article](https://www.ti.com/lit/an/slyt441/slyt441.pdf) , how much = 1 byte transmit command, 3 byte receive data.. how often = every less than 10 seconds.. how fast = max of 2 MHz. By you mean capacitors, decoupling caps parallel on power inputs of rs485 ICs??

Comment: @filo i would like to ask that the short-circuit output current in the datasheet is -150 mA, i have positive rails only. Is this right?

Comment: A popular convention is that current going "into" the IC has a positive sign, current going "out" has a negative sign.